# IE8 does not submit hidden input in form

Tags: html, forms, post, internet-explorer-8

I found this form in a project and it works fine in Chrome but not in Internet Explorer. IE8 does submit the form as POST but does not send the hidden input:

```
    <form name="logout_frm" id="logout" action="index.php" method="post">
        <label>Logout</label>
        <input type="hidden" name="logout" value="1" />
        <input type="submit" name="logoutBtn" value="logout" />
    </form>
```

This is the raw data I get from [fiddle2](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) also WebForms Tab is empty:

```
POST https://example.com/index.php HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, */*
Referer: https://hostname.net/index.php
Accept-Language: de-DE
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729)
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: hostname.net
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cookie: GUEST_LANGUAGE_ID=en_US; COOKIE_SUPPORT=true; ntlm=1; PHPSESSID=28b0fbgol5bnq56qqst423p80ota470sqclbnpc4p5egqqdbt4tw
Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAB4IIogAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbEdAAAAAA==
```

**Update**

If I clear the cache and reload the page it works one time but only once. Maybe this is somehow related to the NTLM login `Authorization: NTLM`.

Comment: It's not generally a good idea to rely on hidden fields anyway, as their value can be easily changed with js or devtools.

Comment: @Mooseman What are you talking about?

Comment: In general @Mooseman is right but in this case the content of the hidden field does not matter and no harm can be done by manipulating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I noticed it is something about [caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434768/prevent-internet-explorer-8-from-caching-form-data) simply disabled it and now it works:

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```

This is not really an answer as it does not explain what is doing on here but it is a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicated the `logout` name. Rename the hidden field or the form.

Comment: I rename the form but it does not make any difference.