# Html hidden fields not submitted with form in IE

Tags: javascript, html

I have some `hidden fields` in the `form` that are not submitted in IE. But working fine in chrome and firefox.

The `Hidden field values` are not appearing in the Request object on submission.

**HTML**

```
 <input type="hidden" name="IsRepeatCustomer" value="" />
 <input type="hidden" name="LeadID" value=""/>
```

I'm setting these hidden code behind

**Code**

Code Block 1

```
var bgColor = Convert.ToInt32(getLeads["NumSales"]) > 0 ? "#B3FFFF" : "#F5D0A9";
                            var isRepeatCustomer = Convert.ToInt32(getLeads["NumSales"]) > 0 ? "Y" : "N";
                            controlBuilder.Append("<tr bgcolor='" + bgColor + "'>");
                            controlBuilder.AppendFormat(@"<td><input type=submit name='submit' onFocus='LeadID.value ={0};IsRepeatCustomer.value=""{1}"";' value='Try This Duplicate' class='button-text' style='background-color: " + bgColor + "; width: 100%' /></td>", getLeads["LeadID"], isRepeatCustomer);
                            controlBuilder.AppendFormat("<td class='boldBodyText' nowrap='nowrap'>{0}&nbsp;</td>", getLeads["FirstName"]);
                            controlBuilder.AppendFormat("<td class='boldBodyText' nowrap='nowrap'>{0}&nbsp;</td>", getLeads["LastName"]);
                            controlBuilder.AppendFormat("<td class='boldBodyText' nowrap='nowrap'>{0}&nbsp;</td>", getLeads["Address"]);
                            controlBuilder.AppendFormat("<td class='boldBodyText' nowrap='nowrap'>{0}&nbsp;</td>", getLeads["Zip"]);
                            controlBuilder.AppendFormat("<td class='boldBodyText' nowrap='nowrap'>{0}&nbsp;</td>", getLeads["Phone"]);
                            controlBuilder.Append("</tr>");
```

So I'm setting the LeadID and IsRepeatCustomer values on Focus of the submit button. The was working fine in Chrome and FireFox.

I'm not sure what to do to make it work in IE.

Code Block 2

```
      private void TryThisDuplicate()
    {
        if (this.IsNewLead(Convert.ToInt32(Request["LeadID"]), Convert.ToInt32(SessionHelper.FirstUserSelectedStoreID)))
        {
            this.LoadQueueDataByDNIS();
            var sourceAndBreakDown = QueueHelper.GetDefaultSourceAndBreakdown(m_Queue);
            if (sourceAndBreakDown.Item1 != null && sourceAndBreakDown.Item2 != null)
            {
                this.UpdateLeadWithSourceAndSourceBreakDown(sourceAndBreakDown.Item1, sourceAndBreakDown.Item2, Convert.ToInt32(Request["LeadID"]), Convert.ToInt32(SessionHelper.FirstUserSelectedStoreID));
            }
        }
        Response.Redirect("/Lead?L=" + Request["LeadID"] + "&SS=Y&P=ADDNEWLEAD&RepeatCustomer=" + Request["IsRepeatCustomer"]);
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962388/ie8-does-not-submit-hidden-input-in-form

Comment: You need to post your code or we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

The placement of the hidden fields matters to IE. i placed the hidden fields inside a table not in a tr or td. just moved the fields to outside. It works.

Answer (score -1):

I also faced such problem sometime back,  I noticed that this is something related to  caching, you can try disabling it by adding below in metadata.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```